# New user in Debian 10 got no Applications Menu nore any bars

Tags: linux, debian, xfce4, user-management

I created a new user in my Debian 10 xfce 4, but it got no menu of applications, no bars above and below, just the desktop. I used the simple command adduser [username].

I really need an GUI solution for that, was examinig mate and other gnome stuff... kinda lost... If does not exists some cool visual user manager for dummies, at list tell me please what options to use to create a normal user with some minimal desktop environment feautures.

Comment: What happens when you login (do you have a graphical login screen?) as the main user, the one you used when installing Debian? Mind the first question `xfce4` asks, and tell it to use the default panels.

Comment: Everthing is normal at login, the user type the password, get in, and it's possible to run everything by right-clicking in the desktop - will open apps menu.

Comment: If you open a terminal and run xfwm4, does anything change? (xfwm4 is the windows manager)

Comment: I deleted the user and created again. I filled myself the forms, there is a welcome box at the beguinning, though my kid click on the wrong choice - instead of default, an empty desktop. Problem solved!